# TraversalEngine abstract class utilisation

Tags: javafx

Firstly, I am sorry but I don't speak English very well. Secondly, I have a problem with nodes which are put in a gridpane. In fact, if the focus is taken by the first one which is located on the top left side, when I push the tab key, the focus is not taken by the other which is located on the right.

People ask me to use the traversalEngine abstract class in order to solve this problem. Nevertheless, when I try to implement an engine object, it doesn't work if I put the parameters which are shown everywhere on the web:

```
TraversalEngine engine = new TraversalEngine(gridPane, false) {
```

It ask me to remove the parameters. If I do it, I don't have access to the trav method. In fact, it is the getRoot method which appears and can be implemented:

```
TraversalEngine engine = new TraversalEngine() {

        @Override
        protected Parent getRoot() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

Is there something which can be make in order to solve this problem?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide an example as described :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The traversal order for focusing nodes in a parent is the order in which they occur in the child list. Assuming every child contains at most one focusable node you could simply add the children line by line or reorder the children.

This could be done programmatically of course, but adding the children in the correct order in the first place would be more efficient...

```
public static int getColumnIndex(Node n) {
    Integer i = GridPane.getColumnIndex(n);
    return i == null ? 0 : i;
}

public static int getRowIndex(Node n) {
    Integer i = GridPane.getRowIndex(n);
    return i == null ? 0 : i;
}
```

```
grid.getChildren().sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ContainingClass::getRowIndex).thenComparingInt(ContainingClass::getColumnIndex));
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I am going to try this tomorrow :).